# Titanium Android webview autolink phone number

Tags: android, webview, titanium, phone-number, linkify

I have a webview with html content written from a mixed xml and html file.
The content have email address and phone number. The code works fine in IPhone. In Android, links are ok, but when I touch over phone number nothing is happening. Does the format of the phone number have to be particular? How can I linkify phone number on webviews on Android?
Thanks for any help!

Best regards 
Manuela

Comment: How is the number formatted now? You can try this in your html `<a href="tel:1235555555">(123) 555-5555</a>`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I can't change the code and the code is something like that:  <p>Tel.<strong>+39 0123 45678</strong><br /></p>

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to make a call when user clicks on "phone_number", you need to write different code for android.

you can write :

```
var num = "12345678";
if(Ti.Platform.osname === 'android')
{
    var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
        action: Ti.Android.ACTION_CALL,
        data: 'tel:'+num
    });
    Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity(intent);
}
else
{
    Titanium.Platform.openURL('tel:'+num);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as adding the "href" property to the telephone number in the HTML.  If that is there, the browser will handle the intent.